# Renaming files in Matlab - movefile is creating folders instead of files

Tags: matlab

The current working directory contains a folder called 'dynamics_sorted' which contains 300 subfolders ('001', '002', etc), each of which contains some files, but only a single nifti (.nii) file.

The single nifti file from each of the numbered subfolders should be moved into 'dynamics_sorted_NIFTI' which is in the current working directory.

In the process, each nifti file should be renamed with the number of its parent folder.

The syntax for movefile suggests that when the arguments are both filenames then the file is renamed

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html#zmw57dd0e528520

```
for Ticker = 1:300;
FindNiftiFile = ['dynamics_sorted/',num2str(Ticker,'%03.0f'),'/*.nii'];
PutNiftiFile = ['dynamics_sorted_NIFTI/',num2str(Ticker,'%03.0f'),'.nii'];
movefile(FindNiftiFile,PutNiftiFile);
end
```

But this code does not rename the files, instead it keeps the filenames but places them into numbered folders.

Any advice as to where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - it's because of the wildcard used to find the source file. I'm guessing this leads Matlab to assume the source is not a single file, even when the wildcard is such that only a single file is eligible.

Comment: This is explicitly stated in the documentation: "To rename a file or folder when moving it, make destination a different name than source, **and specify only one file for source**"